# HGT Elevation vs Calculated Elevation

Tags: gdal, elevation, tools, srtm

I wondering how to interpret the elevation calculation. Per example. We are in Canada and I use SRTM3 files. I use the GDAL library to extract my elevation, everyting is ok, except: Why (or how) the differents tools like WiND (Wireless Node Database), Radio Mobile, Google Earth, Bentley, etc... give the elevation in decimal and the value in the SRTM file is an integer?

I've tried to understand the logical behind this but I never got the same answer for a unique point, except the value in the HGT file, regardless the tool.

My understand is the SRTM3 have a 10 meters precision, SRTM1 32 meters, and the elevation in decimal still defer from both file formats and tools. 4 different tools, 2 different file format, 8 different results... except the HGT file elevation value.

Does anyone have an insight on this?

Comment: Can you post the code you used, or the command line argument you used, with GDAL when extracting your elevation values?